# Cannot find Ruby on Rails installed

Tags: ruby, rails, gem

I've managed to install Ruby and the gems install (rvm?) but now I'm stuck actually installing Ruby on Rails.

Every time I execute, `gem install rails` Terminal says that it's fetching each file and that it successfully installed it:

> 1 gem installed

However when I then run the `rails` command, I'm told that it's not installed and to run the `gem install rails` command again.

I've attempted to install with `sudo` but the same thing happens. I've restarted after an install and that's not worked.

Ideas?

Comment: To help troubleshoot your install, please run the following commands in your terminal ($ is the terminal prompt): $ which rvm $ which ruby $ ruby -v $ gem list

Comment: check your $PATH environment variable.

Comment: Do you see it in the `gem list`?

Answer (score 0):

First select the "global" RVM gemset by

```
rvm gemset use global
```

then install rails and other gems.

```
gem install rails
```

Now it works fine.